# computation of the series $ \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \alpha ^n e^{in\theta}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

im having a hard time computing the following series:

$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty  f_n  e^{in\theta}$

where $f_n=\alpha^n$, $f_n=f^*_{-n}$, $|\alpha|\leq 1$ is complex number and $f_0$ =1 . I can Splitt the series

$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}  (\alpha^*)^n  e^{in\theta} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \alpha^n e^{in\theta} $

Im pretty sure that i need to use the geometrical series but i dont now what to do with  $e^{in\theta} $

Comment: $$\alpha^ne^{in\theta}=(\alpha e^{i\theta})^n.$$

Comment: Ohh :), then i get $ \frac{1}{1- \alpha^*e^{-i\theta}} + \frac{1}{1- \alpha e^{i\theta}}$ Is this correct?

Comment: Mind the central term.

Comment: what do u mean by central term?

Comment: Hem, maybe $n=0$.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your help Sir!